# How does conditional expectation really operate?

Tags: probability

Let there be a keyboard with k keys, only 9 of which are numbers, which are 1,...,9. A monkey performs a series of random taps. The series will end as the monkey taps a non-number key. Let $N$ be the number of different numbers in the series, and let $X$ be the multiplication of these(those?) different numbers. Let us agree in advance that $X=1$ when $N=0$. Find $E[X|N=n]$.

The answers say: $E[X|N=n]=E[\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i]=\prod_{i=1}^{n}E[ X_i]=({1+9\over 2})^n=5^n$. I did go in that direction and did come close, except that I fail to understand how the conditioning part in that expected value computation is taken into consideration. I mean, how do I know it is already taken care of? I only know the technical formula and can't actually discern its fulfillment here. I would appreciate your help here.

Comment: The bit with the k keys strikes me as a red herring.  Given the conditioning, you just have the poor monkey hitting number keys $n$ times.  The fact that something else might have happened is irrelevant.

Comment: @lulu I didn't quite understand the first sentence, but if you are suggesting that it is unpleasantly worded, that is very well possible, as I am not native and the question was translated. As for the second part, well, I do kind of get what you are saying. Did you mean that as soon as we know exactly what the argument precisely is (which is X|N=n here), we can act autonomously? I am getting there, yet have not fully comprehended.

Comment: I was not complaining about your English (which was flawless).  I was protesting the extraneous baggage the problem came with.  But, yes:  my point was that, given the conditioning, I can ignore all the other things that might have happened and just focus on the situation at hand.  I don't, for example, need to concern myself about the probability that I arrived in the given state.

Comment: What the conditioning says is that you know that the monkey has hit numbers n times. Given this information, you can now calculate $E(X)$ just as if $N$ was not random.

Comment: Oh, perhaps you don't know the phrase "red herring".  Can't think why you would, it is an odd phrase.  In brief, it refers to odd clues or bits of information which in reality have nothing to do with the problem at hand.  Here's a discussion of the colorful (and likely apocryphal) origins of the phrase:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30239/where-does-the-phrase-red-herring-come-from

Comment: I know, that is okay if you find things I say funny. I make mistakes that are, at times, foolish and I am fine with it. I was simply pointing out that it is a possibility. :)

Comment: @Augustin Thank you for strengthening the idea. I think I am starting to catch it.

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much for you help in the aforementioned problem and in English as well. I am intrigued and educated by that. This(that?) is a pleasure.

Comment: In full honesty:  I had no idea you were not a native English speaker, didn't even occur to me.  My issue, such as it is, is with texts that clutter up problems with loads of irrelevant information.  I can see where there is sometimes value in asking the reader to sift through the facts to select those that are relevant, but more often than not it just obscures the point under discussion.

Comment: I fully understand. Whenever I can exclude the irrelevant parts, I do, but as most questions I bring up here are taken from a problem consisting of number of questions, sometimes, it is difficult for me to sort the data. That data components are sometimes entangled, making it challenging to separate the wheat from the chaff(I hope I used it correctly.)

Comment: The number of keys is relevant to compute E(X) (probably the next question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf E(X\mid N=n)$ is the (conditional) expected multiple of distinct numbers tapped by the monkey when given that $n$ distinct digit keys are tapped.

Let $X_i$ be the value of the $i$-th distinct key tapped.

Then $\mathsf E(X_i) = \frac {9+1}{2}= 5$ is the expected value of the $i$-th distinct digit.

And so $\mathsf E(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i)$ is the expected multiple of $n$ distinct digits tapped by the monkey.

Hence the expected multiple of distinct numbers tapped by the monkey when $n$ distinct digit keys are tapped is:
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X\mid N=n) & = \mathsf E(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i)
\\ & = \prod_{i=1}^n\mathsf E(X_i)
\\ & = {(\tfrac {10}2)}^{n}
\\ & = 5^n
\end{align}$$